# Change file creation date to TIFF

Tags: python, image, command-line, icloud

I have a problem with dates and iCloud pictures. When I download my pictures from iCloud the creation date of the file is set to the current date and I don't want this. I can change it to the date I want (the one of the day the picture was taken) with "touch -t [date] [file]" but with almost 2000 pictures/videos it would take weeks to achieve that this way.

I know the date the picture was taken thanks to Tools->Show Inspector->Infos->TIFF so the information is clearly contained inside the picture. In the end I wish to modify multiple files creation date at the same time from the command line or with Python.

Can anyone help me please ?

Sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `exiftool` on a couple of sample images in a directory called `SAMPLE`

```
exiftool "-filemodifydate<datetimeoriginal" SAMPLE
```

If that doesn't work, try adding the output from the following command to your question:

```
exiftool SAMPLE_IMAGE.TIF
```